# CakePHP 2.1 date attribute in table

Tags: mysql, date, find, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I have created a table `actor(id, first_name, last_name, dob)`.
Where dob is date of birth and having date format as Y-m-d. I would like to fetch the users who have their birthday on perticular month or perticular day. I have tried it but got solution. Please help me do that.
The work is appreciable.

Comment: have query what u have done.?

Comment: used LIKE for getting only on perticular month and perticular day. But I wanna fetch the actors like from one month to another month and from one day to another day..

Comment: no need to use like in date field there are lot of functions avail

Comment: Would you tell how to do that?

Comment: Please add your expected query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write your condition like code bellow:

```
$conditions = array (
   'AND' => array (
      'MONTH(Actor.dob)' => '12',
      'DAY(Actor.dob)' => '1',
      'YEAR(Actor.dob)' => '2012',
   )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

if particular month (here i have taken second month of year)

```
select * from actor where MONTH(dob)='02'
```

particular day 02.

```
select * from actor where DAY(dob)='02'
```

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you want to know who has it's birth day in this month:

```
$conditions = array(
    'Actor.dob LIKE ?' => CakeTime::format("\%-m\%")
);
```

For today:

```
$conditions = array(
    'Actor.dob LIKE ?' => CakeTime::format("\%-m-d\%")
);
```

You need to be more clear on what you really need to query.